# How to view text logfile on solr?

Tags: solr

I am trying to track down an mysql import error in solr 6.6.5, the UI shows the query but the formating is giving me a headache as this is not the clean txt error but some added formating strings. Plus the MySQL error response is missing.

Where is the txt logfile from solr and is it possible to disable the formating of solr logging UI?

Solr is configured like this:

```
#  Logging level
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, stderr

# log to stderr
log4j.appender.stderr = org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stderr.Target = System.err
log4j.appender.stderr.layout = org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stderr.layout.ConversionPattern=%-5p - %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS}; %C; %m%n

# quiet down the ZK logging for cli tools
log4j.logger.org.apache.zookeeper=WARN
log4j.logger.org.apache.solr.common.cloud=WARN
```

Comment: what OS are you on?

Comment: ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Answer (score 0):

if you did not modify the settings, should be at /var/solr/logs, so you can do

```
tail -n300  /var/solr/logs/solr.log
```